# How can I retarget the framework for a .NET Core application in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-framework-version

I created an empty web project with ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio 2015, but I got a build error:

> Error    MSB3644    The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETFramework,**Version=v4.5.1" were not found**. To resolve this,
>   install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version **or
>   retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you
>   have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed**. Note that assemblies will be
>   resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in
>   place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be
>   correctly targeted for the framework you
>   intend.    G:\projects\temp\WebApplication4\src\WebApplication4\WebApplication4.xproj    C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    1098

#### File *project.json:*

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I have .NET 4.6 & 4.6.1 SDK installed. How can I retarget the framework to 4.6.1?

After reinstalling 4.5.1 SDK, the error is gone. But I still want to retarget to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": { },
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I got an error: "The dependency Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.1 does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1." -- I suspect it's not possible to switch to 4.6.1.

Comment: well there is your answer then that it cannot support 4.6.1. But your question was how to do it and that is how you do it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14628088)

Comment: @Joseph Sorry I am not sure what you mean.